pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed
I face this type error.
Please help me.
Step 5/6 : RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --requirement Installer
 ---> Running in b8cc2d4d4ea3
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.
note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --requirement Installer' returned a non-zero code: 1

Please help me.
In Deploy a Python Telegram bot.

You should edit in the Dockerfile you're using.

Since you're evidently building a Docker container, you can either:

use a virtualenv like the message is guiding you to
actually pass in --break-system-packages, since there is no risk of breaking the system outside the Docker container

